# Is there a way to have a dynamic collection in a sails.js model depending on another attribute within the model?

Tags: sails.js, one-to-many, models, waterline

I have a model (called Model1) like this:

```
/**
* Model1.js
*/

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
       user_type_1: {
             model: "User"
       },
       user_type_2: {
             model: "User"
       },
       user_type_3: {
             model: "User"
       }
    }
};
```

Now I would like my User model to have a collection of Model1 where the via attribute depends on the type of user, like this:

```
/**
* User.js
*/

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
         user_type: "string", //user_type_1, user_type_2, user_type_3
         model1: {
              collection: "Model1",
              via: this.user_type
         }
    }
};
```

This is because each type of user has a different collection of Model1.
Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I create three different attributes for each different user type?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but I know there's a Gitter page for Sails.js. Someone might help there.  https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails